# Increase performance or Code tuning

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
public static List<vwStudentExtendedData> GetStudentExtendedData(List<int> studentIds, DateTime? queryDate, int? sectionId)
{
    var summaries = new List<vwStudentExtendedData>();
    var studentsIDsForSproc = new List<int>();
    foreach (var studentId in studentIds)
    {
        var cachedCopy = CacheHelper.GetFromCache<vwStudentExtendedData>(GetStudentSummaryCacheKey(studentId, queryDate, sectionId));
        if (cachedCopy == null)
        {
            studentsIDsForSproc.Add(studentId);
        }
        else
        {
            summaries.Add(cachedCopy);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to reform this code, because I'm getting performance issue, So I would like to tune the code

Comment: It might make sense to reword your question (better description of what you are after) and ask it on Code Review.

Comment: What's the definition of `performance` issue? What's your benchmark? There are multiple factors which can impact the performance. Such as number of items in `studentIds` collection, code of `CacheHelper.GetFromCache` method, what type of cache you are using.

Comment: By which metrics? Memory usage? CPU time? Wall clock time? And are we allowed to worsen performance on the metrics that aren't important to you? Have you *profiled* your code to confirm that this is in fact the hotspot and so changing it will noticeably *affect* performance?

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the situation (apply profiling or state your target to let us know whether operation is IO/CPU-bound) you may use LINQ or PLINQ or a Producer-Consumer Pattern.

For IO-bound operations LINQ shall perform faster. For CPU bound, i prefer to use Producer-Consumer pattern.